# How can I get data from the same table in one query in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have a problem with my ms access sql query.
I want to have every **ReportPosition** From a **Report**. In every **ReportPosition** There is a Pknr from a deceased its first and lastname and its type. As well as the pknr firstname and lastname of the matching pensioner

I have the following Tables:

**ReportPosition**

```
+-----------------------+---------------+----------+
| ReportPositionId(PK1) | ReportId(PK1) | Pknr(FK) |
+-----------------------+---------------+----------+
|                     1 |             1 |   123121 |
|                     2 |             1 |   456451 |
|                     3 |             1 |   789782 |
+-----------------------+---------------+----------+
```

**Pensioner**

```
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| PKNR(PK) | LastName  | FirstName  | PKNRdeceased | deceasedType |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+
|   123121 | Lastname1 | Firstname1 |       123120 |            1 |
|   456451 | Lastname2 | Firstname2 |       456450 |            1 |
|   789782 | Lastname3 | Firstname3 |       789780 |            2 |
|   123120 | Lastname4 | Firstname4 |            0 |            0 |
|   456450 | Lastname5 | Firstname5 |            0 |            0 |
|   789780 | Lastname6 | Firstname6 |            0 |            0 |
+----------+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**deceasedType**

```
+--------+-------------+
| TypeId |     Bez     |
+--------+-------------+
|      0 | Pensioner   |
|      1 | Widow       |
|      2 | first Child |
+--------+-------------+
```

I need the following output:

```
+----------------+----------+--------+-----------+------------+---
| ReportPosition | ReportId |  PKNR  | lastname  | firstname  |
+----------------+----------+--------+-----------+------------+---
|              1 |        1 | 123121 | lastname1 | firstname1 |
|              2 |        1 | 456451 | lastname2 | firstname2 |
|              3 |        1 | 789782 | lastname3 | firstname3 |
+----------------+----------+--------+-----------+------------+---
--+--------------+--------------+---------------------+--------------------+
  | deceasedtype | PKNRdeceased | lasttname deaceased | firstname deceased |
--+--------------+--------------+---------------------+--------------------+
  |            1 |       123120 | lastname4           | firstname4         |
  |            1 |       456450 | lastname5           | firstname5         |
  |            2 |       789780 | lastname6           | firstname6         |
--+--------------+--------------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

I tried this already but I don't get the desired result:
I used the automatic query creation from access since writing the query manually was to hard for me.

```
    SELECT ReportPosition.ReportPositionId, ReportPosition.ReportId, ReportPosition.PKNR, deceased.lastname, deceased.firstname, PensionerType.Bez, Pensioner.PKNR, Pensioner.lastname, Pensioner.firstname
FROM (PensionerType INNER JOIN (ReportPosition INNER JOIN Pensioner AS deceased ON ReportPosition.PKNR = deceased.PKNR) ON PensionerType.TypeId = deceased.PensionerType) INNER JOIN Pensioner ON deceased.PKNR = Pensioner.pknrdeceased
WHERE ReportPosition.ReportId=1;
```

I need something like a selfjoin because i have to join pensioner with pensioner am I right?

At the moment I don't even get all columns i need. and also not every dataset I want.

Comment: im sorry due to copying and changing the querry I didnt change the number. Its possible that the querry isnt 100% correct for the tables I provided. its use is mainly to show what kind of statement i already tried. since the original table has different datavalues and column names there might still be some faults in the querry as I cant test it with my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't need the `Bez` of the deceased type, you just need to add the `ReportPosition` and `Pensioner` tables, where you add the `Pensioner`table twice:

[image]

Then, add the fields you want to return, where you think of `Pensioner_1` as "the deceased". The SQL of the resulting query should look similar to this:

```
SELECT ReportPosition.ReportPositionId, ReportPosition.ReportId, 
  Pensioner.PKNR, Pensioner.LastName, Pensioner.FirstName, Pensioner.deceasedType, Pensioner.PKNRdeceased, 
  Pensioner_1.LastName AS [Lastname deceased], Pensioner_1.FirstName AS [Firstname deceased]
FROM Pensioner AS Pensioner_1 INNER JOIN 
    (Pensioner INNER JOIN ReportPosition ON Pensioner.PKNR = ReportPosition.Pknr) 
  ON Pensioner_1.PKNR = Pensioner.PKNRdeceased;
```

And of course you can change the alias from `Pensioner_1` to `deceased`.

**Added:**

If you want to display the `Bez` field (instead if `TypeId`), you have to add the `deceasedType` table:

[image]

You can then exchange the `deceasedType` field by the `Bez` field from the newly added table. The SQL of the edited query will look similar to this:

```
SELECT ReportPosition.ReportPositionId, ReportPosition.ReportId,
  Pensioner.PKNR, Pensioner.LastName, Pensioner.FirstName, deceasedType.Bez, Pensioner.PKNRdeceased,
  Pensioner_1.LastName AS [Lastname deceased], Pensioner_1.FirstName AS [Firstname deceased]
FROM deceasedType INNER JOIN
  ((Pensioner AS Pensioner_1 INNER JOIN Pensioner
    ON Pensioner_1.PKNR = Pensioner.PKNRdeceased) INNER JOIN
    ReportPosition ON Pensioner.PKNR = ReportPosition.Pknr)
  ON deceasedType.TypeId = Pensioner.deceasedType;
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. But is there no way to display "Bez" instead of the typeId? This would be nice to have for a better user exerience. but its not a must have.

Comment: Glad to hear that, thanks. As for the `Bez` field, I added an extended query to my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tracked down your exact error, but the query builder in Access creates a very chaotic join notation that's hard to read for me.

As far as I can see, the following should work, though:

```
SELECT ReportPosition.ReportPositionId, ReportPosition.ReportId, ReportPosition.PKNR, deceased.lastname, deceased.firstname, PensionerType.Bez, Pensioner.PKNR, Pensioner.lastname, Pensioner.firstname
FROM (((Pensioner
        INNER JOIN Pensioner AS deceased ON deceased.PKNR = Pensioner.pknrdeceased)
    INNER JOIN PensionerType ON PensionerType.TypeId = deceased.PensionerType)
INNER JOIN ReportPosition ON ReportPosition.PKNR = deceased.PKNR)
WHERE ReportPosition.ReportId=1;
```

Comment: Thank you for trying. After translating the statement and changing the ReportId in the where part to "3" it shows zero datasets eventhough there are 33 datasets in report 3.

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve]. This works on your sample data on properly set-up tables (field type long integer for all numeric types).